# Multiple search on one rowkey in hbase

Tags: hbase

I want to search with multiple parameter on hbase. I'm using JAVA for this. I have many data like following ;

```
 2017-06-14T13:49:41.677Z,0000000000000001,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452872849, value=log_description=s1<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            872849,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:41.677Z,0000000000000002,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452872891, value=log_description=s2<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            872891,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:41.677Z,null,null                         column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452872875, value=log_description=s3<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            872874,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:42.678Z,0000000000000001,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452872903, value=log_description=s1<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            872903,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:42.678Z,0000000000000002,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452872943, value=log_description=s2<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            872943,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:42.678Z,null,null                         column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452872920, value=log_description=s3<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            872920,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:43.677Z,0000000000000001,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452872972, value=log_description=s1<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            872971,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:43.677Z,0000000000000002,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452873027, value=log_description=s2<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            873027,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:43.677Z,null,null                         column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452872999, value=log_description=s3<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            872998,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:44.677Z,0000000000000001,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452873061, value=log_description=s1<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            873060,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:44.677Z,null,null                         column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452873088, value=log_description=s3<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            873088,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:44.678Z,0000000000000002,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452873107, value=log_description=s2<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            873107,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:45.678Z,0000000000000001,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452873256, value=log_description=s1<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            873253,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:45.678Z,0000000000000002,192.168.028.056  column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452873364, value=log_description=s2<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            873364,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
 2017-06-14T13:49:45.678Z,null,null                         column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452873307, value=log_description=s3<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452
                                                            873307,log_module=rconn                                                                                                                                                     
7815 row(s) in 2.1180 seconds
```

For example ; I want to search " log_level=WARN AND log_module=rconn " on this line

```
2017-06-14T13:15:35.678Z,0000000000000001,192 column=log_info:log_data, timestamp=1497452705180, value=log_description=s1<->tcp:192.168.28.56:6633: connection failed (Connection refused),log_level=WARN,log_date=1497452705179,log_module=rconn
```

Can I make that with regex filter?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [RegexStringComparator](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#client.filter.cvp.substringcomparator) in HBase Reference Guide.

Comment: I used RegexFilter  for this example . This filter using regular expressions. My regular expressions;  *.log_level=WARN.*,log_module=rconn $

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to filter according to multiple columns. I guess you can use [RegexStringComparator](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#client.filter.cvp.rcs). If you mean the same one than it is ok.

Comment: @can if you consider my answer as right one please mark it :)